# Angular interpret my date dd/mm/yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy and changed de day and month

Tags: angularjs, date

I send a date to my angularjs app in format 22/03/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy) but angularjs interprets it like mm/dd/yyyy. If I print my day, angularjs return my month.

Any idea of how can I will tell Angularjs that my date is in format dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: you can also use **moment.js** for date format

Comment: Can you please paste your code

Comment: @AmeePrajapati, I used moment, but the problem is that angularjs is chaging my day like month and my month like day, how can I tell angular that my date in 09/05/2016 is 'dd/MM/yyyy' and not 'MM/dd/yyyy'??

Comment: @kfm : Using moment you can do anything date format.
And as you answer so its string reverse so it will convert whole format.

Comment: @AmeePrajapati, thank you! But I fought an easiest way with .split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I just convert my string date like this example:

```
var date = "03/05/2013";
var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");

"2013-05-03"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where and how are you using your date instance. If it's in template then use angular `date` filter. If it's in your controller/service then inject angular `$filter` in your controller/service. You can pass your desired format as input to date filter. Here's the api [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: Perfect Document! My date is in the format 'shortDate': equivalent to 'MM/dd/yyyy' for en_US locale (e.g. 9/3/10). But I'm from Brazil, and I my date is in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'. How can I change this locale? I insert in my index.html the library angular-locale_pt-br.js, but Angularjs is still puting my month like day and my day like month. I have a date um format 'dd/MM/yyyy' but when I pass it to angularjs, angularjs interpret it like 'MM/dd/yyyy'. How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you please share a plnkr or fiddle?